# Showing that a function is Lipschitz.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w$ be complex $n$-dimensional and suppose $f(w)$ is analytic and bounded on the open "rectangle"

$$R: |w-w_0|<b, \quad b>0.$$

Is $f$ Lipschitz on $R$?

---

What I know is that since $f$ is analytic on $R$, its Jacobian matrix is continuous on $R$ and is bounded on any closed rectangle $R' \subseteq R$. Then $f$ must satisfy a Lipschitz condition on $R'.$ Can I conclude from here that $f$ is Lipschitz on $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a counter-example, but I'm a little worried about something like $\sqrt{z}$ on $\{|z-.5|<.5\}\subset \mathbb{C}^1$ (which has an analytic branch defined there, and is bounded). Note that its restriction to the real line is not Lipschitz, in fact, not uniformly continuous.